# A question about java code signing certificate

Tags: java, code-signing-certificate

I downloaded the source code for an applet from here:

http://www.oxygenxml.com/demo/AuthorDemoApplet/author-component-dita.html

As instructed, I've used ANT to build it, however, the build is not successful, the ANT complains like this:

[signJar] jarsigner error:java.Lang.RuntimeException: keystore load :C\Users....{ The system cannot find the file specified}

From this error, I infer it is the java code signing certificate that is causing the problem, and I've done some research about it, it appears to me that I have to purchase. But since I am not deploying this applet to any webserver( including localhost). I was wondering if there is any way that I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is indeed not going to the outside world, or your work will be "trusted" in some other way, you can Self-sign a certificate using the [keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html) tool. It's included in the JDK.

A self signed certificate is one that is not signed by a certificate authority, and therefore you will have no 3rd party vouching for your authenticity, but if this is acceptable (and often it is), this is an appropriate method.

Comment: what if I want a .pfx certificate? Is there anyway that keytool can handle that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own certificate using the jdk tool **keytool**.

Comment: Ah, yes. You can create self-signed one and use it to run it.