# Record Audio As Mp3

Tags: java, php, audio-recording

I want to record audio and save to my server as mp3 files, i googled and find like [this](http://www.vimas.com/mp3.php)

But it is not free and open source

How can i record audio as mp3 in java and php ?

Comment: Is this an application you are running locally or is this something you want to do from a web page?

Comment: So someone will come to a web page, load an applet, then record to the server?

Comment: Yes exactly, is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of Java, you could record with [standard Java sound](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SimpleAudioRecorder.java.html) and then use something like [lameonj](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/) to do the mp3 encoding - all free tools!

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826169/record-voice-with-java) is the same as yours and the person was able to come up with a solution (which he posted as an answer).

A little additional information.  It is possible to record sound in an applet.  See [this page](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_applets.html) for information on Java Sound and applets.  You'll need to sign your applet, which isn't hard to do.  The answer to [question 5](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_applets.html#cas) doesn't mention this but you can create your own (untrusted) certificate with which to do the signing.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776289/a-question-about-java-code-signing-certificate) here on SO has some information on self-signing code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I used lame library to encode mp3, If you want to pure code to encode mp3, you can use [this](http://jsidplay2.cvs.sourceforge.net/jsidplay2/jump3r)

Its using java based lame library